# Lifting weights while watching tv does that qualify as exercise

Tags: weightlifting

I bought a set of weights 10 pound dumbbells and lift them for about 3 or 4 hours while watching tv on my wide screen primarily game of thrones, star trek and the walking dead does this qualify as exercise or no?

Answer (score 1):

While it's good that you've decided to exercise with weights, the real answer to your question can only be found in the amount of **effort** you expend while you perform each movement.  Some would argue that the distraction of the tv would reduce your effort, and, there's probably some truth to that.  While others will say that at least you're doing some physical activity.  I, personally, find using a tv as a distraction while performing aerobics (rowing) helps keep my mind off the pain and effort I feel when pushing myself for more gains.  But, at the same time, I fully understand that the tv is for "background noise" and **not** to be used to grab my attention.

In the end, you're the only one that can decide whether watching tv and exercising is of any value to you.

Comment: I think most people mentally imagine someone lounged on a couch with a dumbbell in hand, vs. a TV on the wall in a workout room.  Yeah, it definitely depends.

Answer (score 1):

Human mind is not designed to do 2 things at a time. You may have heard people multi-tasking, but in reality, they are just switching focus between 2 things. What they claim as multi-task, is actually jumping back and forth between 2 tasks. As a result, productivity suffers at both ends. This may not apply to your situation fully, but if you are watching TV, you are focusing on the show, not on the workout. I'm not saying there isn't any benefit at all, but not as much as a fully-focused workout regime could deliver. There are also chances you may hurt yourself. I know 10 lbs is not much, but good enough to hurt if you drop them by accident.

Why not to take a break from TV while they show those funny ads, and get pumped during that time?

Answer (score 0):

Any kind of sustained physical exertion could be regarded as "exercise," but the real question is, is it **productive** exercise for your desired fitness goals?  Is the intensity, duration, and mechanics consistent with what you want to achieve?

Additionally, consider the safety issues of such a thing.  Any kind of exercise program should be practiced with mindfulness toward the activity, especially any kind of weight training, to avoid injury.  Ideally, you should not be distracted from mentally observing your motion and form.  Lapses in attention are potentially dangerous, even with 10 pound weights.

Finally, you may discover that, overall, it is more productive and enjoyable to separate your leisure activities from you training activities, because if you focus on each one separately, you will find you spend less time exercising to gain at least as much, if not more, in terms of your fitness goals, and you will be able to pay full attention to your television programs.  In a way, just like it is important to be mindful during training, it is also important to be mindful during entertainment, because this creates a more immersive experience.